# SQL - Auto paginating a catalogue

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I'm building a model to auto populate (paginate) a catalogue with products.

I have a running order, and the space allocation each product should receive (1/8 1/4 1/2 3/4 1/1 pages).

I need ideas on how to tessellate the products onto page. without too much space wasted.

E.g. part 1 needs 1/8 page part 2 needs a full page... normal logic would put part 2 on the next page. Common sense would put them on a single page together. (There will be many many variations on this example).

The running order cannot be changed.

Thanks

Sample of data here:

```
CREATE TABLE #tt1 
  ( 
     productid        INT, 
     pages            DECIMAL(4, 2), 
     pagination_order INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006691, 
       0.125, 
       1 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007836, 
       1, 
       2 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005073, 
       0.125, 
       3 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1004985, 
       1, 
       4 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007840, 
       0.5, 
       5 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007841, 
       0.5, 
       6 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1008032, 
       1, 
       7 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007845, 
       0.5, 
       8 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006688, 
       0.25, 
       9 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005890, 
       0.75, 
       10 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006658, 
       0.5, 
       11 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006654, 
       0.25, 
       12 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006653, 
       0.5, 
       13 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005066, 
       0.5, 
       14 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006648, 
       0.25, 
       15 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1004970, 
       0.5, 
       16 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1004953, 
       0.25, 
       17 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006024, 
       1, 
       18 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007844, 
       0.5, 
       19 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010035, 
       0.25, 
       20 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010106, 
       0.25, 
       21 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010036, 
       0.125, 
       22 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010107, 
       0.25, 
       23 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010004, 
       0.125, 
       24 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010000, 
       0.5, 
       25 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010003, 
       0.25, 
       26 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007835, 
       0.25, 
       27 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010116, 
       0.125, 
       28 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010104, 
       0.25, 
       29 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010033, 
       0.5, 
       30 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010034, 
       0.5, 
       31 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006590, 
       0.125, 
       32 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1008999, 
       0.25, 
       33 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005080, 
       0.125, 
       34 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006779, 
       0.5, 
       35 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1008989, 
       0.25, 
       36 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005068, 
       0.5, 
       37 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006650, 
       0.25, 
       38 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005070, 
       0.5, 
       39 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006693, 
       0.25, 
       40 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007981, 
       0.25, 
       41 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010022, 
       0.25, 
       42 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1009842, 
       0.5, 
       43 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005069, 
       0.25, 
       44 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000643, 
       0.25, 
       45 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002611, 
       0.125, 
       46 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000714, 
       1, 
       47 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007983, 
       0.25, 
       48 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006717, 
       0.25, 
       49 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1009846, 
       0.25, 
       50 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1009845, 
       0.25, 
       51 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002559, 
       0.125, 
       52 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010006, 
       0.25, 
       53 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006742, 
       0.5, 
       54 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1004952, 
       1, 
       55 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1009855, 
       0.5, 
       56 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1009876, 
       0.75, 
       57 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000556, 
       0.25, 
       58 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010085, 
       0.125, 
       59 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010086, 
       0.125, 
       60 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000888, 
       0.125, 
       61 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000672, 
       0.125, 
       62 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010077, 
       0.125, 
       63 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000550, 
       0.125, 
       64 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000551, 
       0.125, 
       65 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002409, 
       0.125, 
       66 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002402, 
       0.25, 
       67 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005870, 
       0.25, 
       68 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006594, 
       0.125, 
       69 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002494, 
       1, 
       70 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002307, 
       0.125, 
       71 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000662, 
       0.5, 
       72 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002587, 
       0.25, 
       73 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002563, 
       0.25, 
       74 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000703, 
       0.5, 
       75 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1009404, 
       0.25, 
       76 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000975, 
       0.25, 
       77 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002562, 
       0.125, 
       78 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000645, 
       1, 
       79 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007980, 
       0.125, 
       80 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002225, 
       0.25, 
       81 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005092, 
       0.25, 
       82 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1009840, 
       0.25, 
       83 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006649, 
       0.25, 
       84 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1004959, 
       0.25, 
       85 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000604, 
       0.25, 
       86 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005021, 
       0.25, 
       87 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007846, 
       0.75, 
       88 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002519, 
       0.125, 
       89 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006675, 
       0.125, 
       90 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000541, 
       0.125, 
       91 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006676, 
       0.125, 
       92 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006784, 
       0.125, 
       93 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002357, 
       0.25, 
       94 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002355, 
       0.5, 
       95 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1009841, 
       0.25, 
       96 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1009858, 
       0.125, 
       97 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005866, 
       0.25, 
       98 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1005878, 
       0.125, 
       99 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1004962, 
       0.125, 
       100 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006768, 
       0.25, 
       101 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000704, 
       0.125, 
       102 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000589, 
       0.125, 
       103 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002276, 
       0.125, 
       104 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000940, 
       0.125, 
       105 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000648, 
       0.25, 
       106 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000588, 
       0.25, 
       107 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002560, 
       0.125, 
       108 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1001655, 
       0.5, 
       109 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002580, 
       0.25, 
       110 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1004961, 
       0.125, 
       111 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1004986, 
       0.125, 
       112 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002312, 
       0.125, 
       113 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1004918, 
       0.125, 
       114 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000706, 
       0.5, 
       115 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1004958, 
       0.125, 
       116 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1002315, 
       0.5, 
       117 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1003026, 
       0.25, 
       118 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010083, 
       0.125, 
       119 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007902, 
       0.25, 
       120 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010082, 
       0.125, 
       121 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006620, 
       0.25, 
       122 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007867, 
       0.125, 
       123 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006740, 
       0.25, 
       124 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007939, 
       0.125, 
       125 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006642, 
       0.125, 
       126 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1006641, 
       0.125, 
       127 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007938, 
       0.25, 
       128 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1010046, 
       0.25, 
       129 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1003014, 
       0.25, 
       130 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1003041, 
       0.125, 
       131 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1007866, 
       0.125, 
       132 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1003035, 
       0.125, 
       133 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000857, 
       0.125, 
       134 

INSERT INTO #tt1 
SELECT 1000852, 
       0.125, 
       135
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? That's pretty relevant. Also, can you give the expected output given your sample data?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014. I'm after a way to get alter the "pages" in order to fit the parts on each page so that there is very little space wasted

Comment: So in the example above, page 1 would consist of a single part, but this part should only get 1/8th of a page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then I think that this will give you what you want:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
SELECT
    productid,
    pages,
    SUM(pages) OVER (ORDER BY pagination_order) AS current_page_unrounded
FROM
    #tt1
)
SELECT
    productid,
    pages,
    CEILING(current_page_unrounded) AS page_number
FROM
    MyCTE
```

The windowed use of `SUM` lets you get a running total, then you just need to use `CEILING` to round up to the page number where the product would appear.

Keep in mind that this will preserve pagination order at all costs, so no optimizations for fitting things to a page will be done.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was using a self join to do this:
select t.ProductID
 , t.Pages
 , t.Pagination_Order
 , ceiling(sum(t2.Pages)) as Page
from #tt1 t
join #tt1 t2 on t.Pagination_Order >= t2.Pagination_Order
group by t.ProductID 
 , t.Pages
 , t.Pagination_Order

Comment: however the optimizations for fitting things to a page will be done is important as i'm restricted on total number of pages and to avoid the wasted space

Comment: If you want some sort of optimizations on page placement then you'll need to describe your algorithm for that and include actual expected output.